# Perl - XML::LibXML - getting elements that have certain attributes

Tags: xml, perl, xpath, xml-parsing, xml-libxml

I have a problem I am hoping someone can help with...

I have the following example xml structure:

```
<library>
    <book>
       <title>Perl Best Practices</title>
       <author>Damian Conway</author>
       <isbn>0596001738</isbn>
       <pages>542</pages>
       <image src="http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/covers/perlbp.s.gif"
            width="145" height="190" />
    </book>
    <book>
       <title>Perl Cookbook, Second Edition</title>
       <author>Tom Christiansen</author>
       <author>Nathan Torkington</author>
       <isbn>0596003137</isbn>
       <pages>964</pages>
       <image src="http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/covers/perlckbk2.s.gif"
            width="145" height="190" />
    </book>
    <book>
       <title>Guitar for Dummies</title>
       <author>Mark Phillips</author>
       <author>John Chappell</author>
       <isbn>076455106X</isbn>
       <pages>392</pages>
       <image src="http://media.wiley.com/product_data/coverImage/6X/0750/0766X.jpg"
           width="100" height="125" />
    </book>
</library>
```

Code that I thought should work:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::LibXML;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $xmldoc = $parser->parse_file('/path/to/xmlfile.xml');

my $width = "145";

my $query = "//book/image[\@width/text() = '$width']/author/text()";

foreach my $data ($xmldoc->findnodes($query)) {
    print "Results: $data\n";
}
```

**Expected output:**

Damian Conway
Tom Christiansen

but I do not get anything returned.

**I thought this would match the text content of any "author" elements within a "book" element which also contains an "image" element with an attribute 'width' that has a value of 145.**

I'm sure I'm overlooking something very obvious here but cannot work out what I am doing wrong.

Your help is much appreciated thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there. Just notice that `author` is not a child of `image`. Attributes do not have text() children, you can compare their values directly with strings. Also, `toString` is needed to print the values out instead of references.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::LibXML;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $xmldoc = $parser->parse_file('1.xml');

my $width = "145";

my $query = "//book[image/\@width = '$width']/author/text()";

foreach my $data ($xmldoc->findnodes($query)) {
    print "Results: ", $data->toString, "\n";
}
```

Comment: Re "toString is needed to print the values out instead of references", Really? Not for me.

Comment: @ikegami: I am getting `Results: XML::LibXML::Text=SCALAR(0x90e0230)` if I do not use it.

Comment: Stringification overloaded must have been added to XML::LibXML since your version. Good to know it wasn't always there.

Comment: @ikegami: Yes, I had a feeling I already hadn't needed it somewhere, probably a different machine. Changelog shows "2.0012   Fri  9 Nov 06:39:32 IST 2012 - Fix support for references to scalars with overloaded stringification magic."

Comment: @choroba @ikegami Also, when using something such as `//book/image/\@height` to get all height attributes (using a foreach loop), when I print using $data->toString it prints the tag name as well such as height="190", height="190", height="125" rather than just 190, 190, 125. How are you able to just print the tag value and tag name seperatly? thanks

Comment: @ikegami One of your answers to another question helped, i needed to use `$data->textContent` instead of `$data->toString`. thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Building in choroba's answer]

In a situation where it's not safe to interpolate `$width` (e.g. if it might contain a `'`), you can use:

```
for my $book ($xmldoc->findnodes('/library/book')) {
    my $image_width = $book->findvalue('image/@width');
    next if !$image_width || $image_width ne '145';

    for my $data ($book->findnodes('author/text()')) {
        print "Results: ", $data->toString, "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

XML attributes don't have text nodes, so your `$query` should have been `"//book/image[\@width='$width']/author/text()"`