# Perl XML::LibXML very slow processing due to slope within elements

Tags: xml, perl, libxml2, xml-libxml

I wrote a code to import an xml-file into a database and encountered a huge performance problem. The xml-file has 150 Mb and contains 170,000 elements (ART) with corresponding subelements (REF_DATA, ...). I was able to find out the cause of the problem but I don't know how to solve it.

Each element ART has subelements (see figure). The problem arises in case where I have several subelements ARTPRI within ART which are distincted bei their subelements PTYP. I would like to extract each data ARTPRI/VDAT and ARTPRI/PRICE and import into variables `$v_dat_pexf`, `$v_dat_ppub`,`$v_dat_zurr`, etc.

Below is a **minimal** example of my code. This code needs 30 seconds to read one element ART. When I remove the part (START node2 / END node2) then the xml-file is processed very fast (< 1s/ART).

Does anyone have an idea why this part of the code slows down the process and how to cope with that?
Thanks for help.

Here is the xml-file:
[image: xml-file]

And this is the code:

```
my $xml_article = "oddb_article.xml";
my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new();
$xpc->registerNs(sr => 'http://whatever');
my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $xml_article);

my @node1_art = $xpc->findnodes("/sr:ARTICLE/sr:ART", $doc);
my $i = 0;
foreach my $node1 ( @node1_art ) {
    $i++;
    my $ref_data           = $xpc->findvalue('./sr:REF_DATA',$node1);
    my @node1_art_artpri   = $xpc->findnodes("/sr:ARTICLE/sr:ART/sr:ARTPRI", $doc);
    my $v_dat_pexf;

    # -- search through each ARTPRI within ART
    # (This is the part which slows down processing)
    # -------- START node2 -----------------------
    foreach my $node2 ( @node1_art_artpri ) {
        my $ctrl1 = $xpc->findvalue('./sr:PTYP',$node2);
        if ( $ctrl1 eq 'PEXF' ) {
        $v_dat_pexf = $xpc->findvalue('./sr:VDAT',$node2);
        }
    # -------- END node2 -----------------------
    }     
print "Row $i\n";
}
```

Here a version for copy-paste with 3 elememts of ART:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ARTICLE xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://whatever" CREATION_DATETIME="2015-11-17T05:44:14+0100" PROD_DATE="2015-11-17T05:44:14+0100" VALID_DATE="2015-11-17T05:44:14+0100">
  <ART DT="" SHA256="2744a856e9bdf226e68bd555f0695b37f6477c55fca3d9eec36a0740fe8146c2">
    <REF_DATA>1</REF_DATA>
    <PHAR>0000000</PHAR>
    <SALECD>I</SALECD>
    <CDBG>N</CDBG>
    <BG>N</BG>
    <DSCRD>Epimineral Paste</DSCRD>
    <DSCRF>Epimineral pâte</DSCRF>
    <SORTD>EPIMINERAL PASTE</SORTD>
    <SORTF>EPIMINERAL PâTE</SORTF>
    <ARTCOMP>
      <COMPNO>7601003300741</COMPNO>
    </ARTCOMP>
    <ARTBAR>
      <CDTYP>E13</CDTYP>
      <BC>0</BC>
      <BCSTAT>A</BCSTAT>
    </ARTBAR>
    <ARTPRI>
      <VDAT>01.10.2015</VDAT>
      <PTYP>PEXF</PTYP>
      <PRICE>305.83</PRICE>
    </ARTPRI>
    <ARTPRI>
      <VDAT>01.10.2015</VDAT>
      <PTYP>PPUB</PTYP>
      <PRICE>367.5</PRICE>
    </ARTPRI>
    <ARTINS>
      <NINCD>10</NINCD>
    </ARTINS>
  </ART>
  <ART DT="" SHA256="ac0eb1ad7c81f5476541ead533c48690a2c9cf3b1dd0ba8ae295145b6bcb1b40">
    <REF_DATA>0</REF_DATA>
    <PHAR>0021976</PHAR>
    <SALECD>I</SALECD>
    <CDBG>N</CDBG>
    <BG>N</BG>
    <DSCRD>DIOPARINE Gtt Opht 7500 E 5 ml</DSCRD>
    <DSCRF>DIOPARINE Gtt Opht 7500 E 5 ml</DSCRF>
    <SORTD>DIOPARINE GTT OPHT 7500 E 5 ML</SORTD>
    <SORTF>DIOPARINE GTT OPHT 7500 E 5 ML</SORTF>
    <ARTCOMP/>
    <ARTBAR>
      <CDTYP>E13</CDTYP>
      <BC>0</BC>
      <BCSTAT>A</BCSTAT>
    </ARTBAR>
    <ARTPRI>
      <VDAT>01.10.2015</VDAT>
      <PTYP>PEXF</PTYP>
      <PRICE>305.83</PRICE>
    </ARTPRI>
    <ARTPRI>
      <VDAT>01.10.2015</VDAT>
      <PTYP>PPUB</PTYP>
      <PRICE>367.5</PRICE>
    </ARTPRI>
  </ART>
  <ART DT="" SHA256="ecc62600e79183822abddb3af0d2a1f9dfb9f2c343c51a2cf135a45354ba7de1">
    <REF_DATA>0</REF_DATA>
    <PHAR>0027447</PHAR>
    <SALECD>I</SALECD>
    <CDBG>N</CDBG>
    <BG>N</BG>
    <DSCRD>ARTHROSENEX Salbe 100 g</DSCRD>
    <DSCRF>ARTHROSENEX Salbe 100 g</DSCRF>
    <SORTD>ARTHROSENEX SALBE 100 G</SORTD>
    <SORTF>ARTHROSENEX SALBE 100 G</SORTF>
    <ARTCOMP/>
    <ARTBAR>
      <CDTYP>E13</CDTYP>
      <BC>0</BC>
      <BCSTAT>A</BCSTAT>
    </ARTBAR>
    <ARTPRI>
      <VDAT>01.10.2015</VDAT>
      <PTYP>PEXF</PTYP>
      <PRICE>305.83</PRICE>
    </ARTPRI>
    <ARTPRI>
      <VDAT>01.10.2015</VDAT>
      <PTYP>PPUB</PTYP>
      <PRICE>367.5</PRICE>
    </ARTPRI>
  </ART>
  <RESULT>
    <OK_ERROR>OK</OK_ERROR>
    <NBR_RECORD>170673</NBR_RECORD>
    <ERROR_CODE/>
    <MESSAGE/>
  </RESULT>
</ARTICLE>
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal XML structure that we can copy/paste please? The screenshot is not very usefull for trying.

Comment: @simbabque I added the xml. Thanks for reply.

Comment: What are you needing as the result of your parse? This might be better done with a different library. (to keep memory footprint down - `XML::LibXML` is generally good, it's just it works on a whole document)

Comment: @simbabque The content has to be loaded into MySQL-database. Which alternative? I already changed from XML::PATH to XML::LibXML since the formerly seems to be deprecated.

Comment: For big XML where I'm extracting limited amounts of data, `XML::Twig` is pretty good, because it can parse "stream style" - pick out the bits you want, and throw the rest away by `purge` or `twig_roots`. (`XML::LibXML` remains a good choice with working with whole documents)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the root of your problem will be the combination of these two lines:

```
my @node1_art = $xpc->findnodes("/sr:ARTICLE/sr:ART", $doc);


my @node1_art_artpri   = $xpc->findnodes("/sr:ARTICLE/sr:ART/sr:ARTPRI", $doc);
```

Because it looks like you're finding every `ART` node across the whole document (scanning the whole thing) and then for every such node - you're scanning the whole document *again* to find every `ARTPRI` node.

Which you're then iterating in:

```
foreach my $node2 ( @node1_art_artpri ) {
```

... but only capturing the value of the last one you find.

That looks like it might be a logic error (hard to tell for sure).

But have you tried just printing each time that loop iterates, and see how many times it does?

Because it *looks* like the intent is to only go a small number of times. You only have two `ARTPRI` nodes beneath your example `ART` but it'll be doing so considerably more.

This should be fixable by:

```
my @node1_art_artpri   = $xpc->findnodes("./sr:ARTPRI", $node1);
```

(or something similar - the important part is to set the context to the node, not the doc).

Or perhaps making use of `xpath` instead of your logical condition:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new();
$xpc->registerNs( sr => 'http://whatever' );
my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => 'test4.xml' );

foreach my $node1 ( $xpc->findnodes( "/sr:ARTICLE/sr:ART", $doc ) ) {
    my $ref_data = $xpc->findvalue( './sr:REF_DATA', $node1 );
    my $v_dat_pexf =
        $xpc->findvalue( './sr:ARTPRI/sr:PTYP[text()="PEXF"]/../sr:VDAT', $node1 );
    print "$ref_data => $v_dat_pexf\n";
}
```

But actually for this sort of task, I might be thinking in terms of `XML::Twig`, which lets you do things via `twig_handlers` - and thus keep memory footprint down.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

sub extract_pexf {
   my ( $twig, $ART ) = @_; 
   #or stuff it in an array, whatever. 
   print $ART -> first_child_text('REF_DATA'), " => ";
   print $ART -> get_xpath('.//ARTPRI/PTYP[string()="PEXF"]/../VDAT',0) -> text,"\n";
   $twig -> purge; #clear processed data from memory. 
}

XML::Twig -> new ( twig_handlers => { 'ART' => \&extract_pexf } ) -> parsefile ( 'your_xml' );
```

Comment: You are right! It retrieves allways the same value.

Comment: Thanks for Twig. I will try first a solution for LibXML. Some how it should be possible to the loop only into ART. I found a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249874/perl-xmllibxml-getting-elements-that-have-certain-attributes), but can't reproduce it with my example probably due to namespace/LibXML syntax.

Comment: The reason that article doesn't work is because you're not looking for attrites, but rather content. I have edited with an `XML::LibXML` example that I think should do the trick (works on the cut down sample) - but you are going  to always have memory footprint to consider.

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved my week. This syntax `$xpc->findvalue( './sr:ARTPRI/sr:PTYP[text()="PEXF"]/../sr:VDAT', $node1 )` is very flexible. I wonder where is the documentation for this kind of syntax-rules. In LixXML I coudn't find it.

Comment: That's not so much `XML::LibXML` as `xpath` http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp